# How to assign js value to the java variable?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

```
<select name="DB">
<option value="findmaximum" onclick="functionse()" style=font-size:20px>findmaximum</option>
<option value="marklist" onclick="functionse()"style=font-size:20px>marklist</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

function functionse(){
    var DBname=document.getElementsByName('DB');
    
    <%
        String DBname = (String) request.getAttribute("DB");
                System.out.println(DBname);
                ResultSet resultsettable=DBconnector.tables(DBname);
               String Tablenames[]=new String[0];
        int i=0;
    while(resultsettable.next()){
       String Tablename=resultsettable.getString("TABLE_NAME");
        Tablenames[i++]=Tablename;
        }

       %>
}
```

print DBname vaule but return null

Comment: Do not use db connections directly in a jsp

Comment: You can't access `DBname` in the scriptlet as they're executed at different times. The scriptlet is executed on the server, i.e. when the page is constructed, the JavaScript code runs in the browser, i.e. _after_ the page has been delivered.

Comment: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429)